# Unicode subscript in R

Tags: r, unicode

I want to write `\sigma^2_i` using unicode I can get two-thirds of the way there with:

```
"\u03C3\U00B2"
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to add subscript. According to [this site where I got the unicode for superscript 2](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d62/index.htm) the correct unicode for subscript i is `"\u1D62"`, but in R this does not print subscript i.

I know that for text in plots you can use `expression`, but this is not for a plot, so `expression` does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

edit: it appears that using `cat` evaluates unicode in cases when just printing doesn't necessarily evaluate the unicode. I still don't understand why the unicode characters are inconsistent. Per this [website](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2096/index.htm) the unicode character for subscript k is `"\u2096"`, but `cat("\u2096")` prints a thick |

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: `plot(1,1, xlab=expression(sigma[i]^2))`

Comment: I am aware of `expression`, but it doesn't help me outside of plots

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example so that we can provide code that applies to your specific context. Is this a table, rmarkdown document, or...? For text in an rmarkdown (or sweave) document, it would be `$\sigma_i^2$`.

Comment: I simply want to print in r console. See my example above where I have the sigma squared part working

Comment: Strangely, the superscript "i" works in the console `"\u03C3\U2071\U00B2"`, but as you noted, the subscript does not.

Comment: Yeah, I think unicode is wonky and OS specific (could be wrong). The superscript i you put above doesn't work for me, I get an | bar.

Comment: Hmm, `cat("\u03C3\U1D62\U00B2")` works for me, but the bare string does not.

Comment: Good point @alistaire, but I still don't get why only some unicode characters work as expected.

Comment: Some fonts may allow only a small fraction of the universe ofUnicode to be displayed. Find a font that represent your codes the way you expect.

Comment: Nice one @alistaire. That works on my Mac as well.